# Git clone fails: unable to create file. Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: git, encoding, character-encoding

I do a `git clone repository` on a new computer. However when I do that, the following happens:

```
Cloning into 'repository'...
remote: Counting objects: 12934, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9861/9861), done.
remote: Total 12934 (delta 3121), reused 12153 (delta 2963)
Receiving objects: 100% (12934/12934), 642.07 MiB | 138.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3121/3121), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
error: unable to create file 2017/08/07/sensitivepath/-A�%88scblabla?resize=800%2C600& (Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character)
Checking out files: 100% (13426/13426), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Now, there was an issue, related to this commit, a couple of weeks ago where we had to reset to a previous commit and put all servers to run on that commit (all servers did a `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master` if I recall correctly). The thing is, that file in particular was downloaded using wget and when trying to manipulate it with python (sadly, 2.7.12 and not 3.4 or 3.5) it also crashed the application.

Now, I thought I would be able to do the `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master` commands on the failed clone to get it right, but I get the issue:

```
error: unable to create file 2017/08/07/sensitivepath/-A�%88scblabla?resize=800%2C600& (Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character)
Checking out files: 100% (13426/13426), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
```

The git status gives me an awful commit which was undone a long time ago (in other versions of the repository we do git pull nowadays whenever we push new code and it is working fine...).

So, I proceed to do `git checkout -f HEAD` and then `git pull`, which works. And for now, all automation on this matter includes this commands, but this seems like it shouldn't happen.

How can I get rid of this file that provokes this error or what is the correct way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's all wrapped up into one convenient command, `git clone` essentially consists of:

- `mkdir`: create an empty directory to hold a repository;
- `git init`: fill in that empty directory with a new, as-yet-empty repository;
- `git remote add origin <url>`: configure the empty repository to have a remote named `origin`;
- `git fetch origin`: obtain all the *commits* (and tags and any related objects) from the remote just added;
- and last, `git checkout <something>`.

It's the last part that's failing, and for the reason you suggest (that there's a file name that your underlying OS rejects, that some other OS must have accepted since it got into the commit in question).

The interesting thing here is the `<something>` part, which you can control.  If you choose *not* to control it, your Git—the one making the directory, creating a repository, and so on—asks the *other* Git, at the other end of the `<url>`, which branch is the default branch.

Usually, that's `master`, but any branch can be the default.  It's up to whoever controls that *other* Git repository to configure the default.  The way to configure that depends on how that other Git repository itself is managed (which you have not mentioned here).

But since you have control over what *your* Git checks out, you can simply tell *your* Git to check out a known-good branch name:

```
git clone -b known_good_branch <url>
```

Now, you should not have to re-clone just because the `git checkout` step failed: you should be able to just `git checkout -b known_good_branch` at this point, in this repository that `git clone` made and fetched and then tried-and-failed to check out the "bad" branch-tip.  But it would also be wise to go fix the repository from which you are cloning, so that its default branch—whatever that is—points to a "good" commit, either by changing *which* branch is the default, or by adding a "good" commit at the end of the current (bad) default branch, or both.

Comment: Thanks torek. I'm pretty sure you got most of it right, although there are a few strange things: All OS were Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. No other OSs have touched the repo. Another thing is that by doing git checkout -f HEAD and git pull, it works. At this moment, there is only a single branch on this repo (it is mostly an automated repo controlled by an application written in python). In the current commit, that file does not exist.

Comment: OK, that's especially weird then: Git should be able to check out any name on most Ubuntu file systems (exceptions might include various distributed ones). The error message might occur when trying to *print out* the name, if it's not a valid UTF-8 encoded name for instance. (You're not using Git-LFS, or some similar front end, are you? I was assuming Windows or OSX as those are fussy about file names.)

Comment: BTW, as a diagnostic, you can run `git ls-remote origin` from any of the clones, to see what references exist on the Git at `origin`. This should start with some hash ID and `HEAD`, and the hash ID here should generally match that of some other branch. If it's "wrong" that is the source of the failing checkout.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. As you can guess, lots of work. Nothing especial, just basic ubuntu with git and using bitbucket for hosting (but no actions are done on bitbucket, it is all automated on the python system). I did what you said and found nothing out of place. I have decided to let this thing rest for now, mostly because there's other more important things on the work bucket right now. I am still curious about whatever happened and will try to find out when I have time, and will report here if I find it.